# Getting an error 8007002C-4001E after trying to installing Windows 10 on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 7 and tried installing Windows 10 and I keep getting the following error after installing:

> installation failed in SECOND_BOOT phase with an error during PRE_OOBE
>   operation

My laptop then would revert to Windows 7 again. I’ve deleted all files in `SoftwareDistribution` and `DataScore` folders but I still get this error. What should I do?

Comment: [See if the answers give here solve it for you](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/0x8007002c-0x4001c-error-while-installing-windows/cc435d09-27d4-42f8-a447-af830b340613?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with my upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  I eventually managed to resolve this with the following process, and it does not involve changing any data.

1. Disable both the Wireless and wired network cards in the Control Panel and then start the installation again.

The reason that I think it fails is that (in my opinion) it tries to authenticate with a Windows account, which windows 7 did not have. If you can boot into Windows 10 for the first time, it will enable the network adapters again and all will be well.  All of my Windows 8 upgrades worked without having to do this, so I gather this must be specific to Windows 7.

I have tested the upgrade process on 4 x Windows 7 PCs so far and with all of them this worked. If this does not work you can also do the following:

1. Uninstall your AV program
2. Remove any non-MS processes from the startup in MS-Config
3. Disable any non-essential devices in Device Manager (including the NICs)
4. Reboot the PC and start the upgrade again.

Please let me know how it turns out for you.

Comment: Since you're upgrading with the network card turned off, can I assume you're upgrading from an ISO image?

Answer (score 0):

Finally A GUARANTEED  SOLUTION TO Error Code 8007002

1- All you have to do is to download a program by Microsoft called Autoruns
Autoruns Download Link

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

2- in this program (Autoruns) you will find literally every program, service, drive, etc.. that starts during & after system boot (startup).

```
   A - In the program options, Make sure that  (Hide Microsoft Entries) & (Hide Windows Entries) are ticked, This insures that you don't accidentally disable any of the files required by the system to function correctly

   B - Now got the Logon Tab  & untick (uncheck) all the entries, DO NOT DELETE the entries just untick them

   C - Then do the same thing in the Scheduled Tasks Tab

   D - Also untick (uncheck) all the entries in the  Service Tab

   E - Now go to the Drivers Tab, You have to be EXTRA CAREFUL in this tab, Some of the entries in this tab are required by the system to boot & unchecking them will definitely damage your system, DO NOT Randomly untick the entries of this tab, look at the Description & Publisher columns in the program to determine which entries to untick, The entries that should Be unticked are the:



                         - (Graphic Drivers):
```

in my case the graphic drive is NVIDIA so i unticked all the entries from NVIDIA

```
                         - (Network Drivers):
```

Untick all the network drivers found, For me there was many (Media Tek Wireless, Huawei USB Modem, AnchorFree For Hotspot Sheild VPN, etc..) as i said you have to look at the [Publisher column] to know what the entry represent

```
                          - (Audio Drivers):
```

Like (RealTek HD Audio) or any other audio driver

```
                           - (3rd Party Drivers):
```

Untick any 3d party driver, & by third party drivers i mean the drivers added by programs you installed like (Internet Download Manger WFP Driver) & (Samsung USB Driver) etc..

```
   F - Now go to the Codecs Tab, untick all the entries that could be unticked (some will remain ticked no matter what), Alternatively you can uninstall the codec software installed in your computer Like (K-lite Codec) or (Shark007 Codec )
```

3- Now you can close the program & proceed with the Windows 10 upgrade

4- After the end of the Windows 10 upgrade process SURPRISE Windows Successfully upgraded to Windows 10, no more Restore Previous System, no more Error Code 8007002

5- After The Upgrade, run the (Autoruns) program & tick all the entries you unticked previously